# hadoop + Flume + HDFS IO error + ConnectException

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume-ng

I'm working with Cloudera Manager CDH 5.4.2, also installed Flume, I can not save the information that I get from Twitter

When I run the flume agent, it starts okay but ends up in error when it attempts writing the new event data into hdfs.
 I got the following error:

```
 INFO org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating hdfs://192.168.109.6:8020/user/flume/tweets/2015/06/03/06//FlumeData.1433311217583.tmp

WARN org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink: HDFS IO error
java.net.ConnectException: Call From cluster-05.xxxx.com/192.168.109.6 to cluster-05.xxxx.com:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

The configuration that I did was :

flume-conf.property:

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://192.168.109.6:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
```

I using the follown pluggins:

```
flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar
twitter4j-media-support-2.2.6.jar
twitter4j-stream-2.2.6.jar
```

(I replace the version of the twitter4j-*-3.0.3.jar for the twitter4j-*-2.2.6.jar)

also the directory using hdfs user

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/flume : 
drwxrwxrwx - flume flume  /user/flume/tweets
```

core-site.xml ( at /hadoop/conf ) I Added:

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

I also run hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave on the host where I left the Flume Agent as HDFS user

I really appreciate your help, on this issue.

Comment: Try replacing `localhost` in core-site.xml with `192.168.109.6` (your namenode IP or FQDN).